# Full gaps in the curve

Tags: data-cleaning

[image]

This is the data from Irelands vaccine program. There are these missing bits of data.

Is there away to fill these gaps with proportional data to make a smooth curve?

Answer (score 0):

```
ire_vax_df = ire_vax_df.interpolate()
```